# Eliminar elementos DIV javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy intentando eliminar todos los elementos de la clase `cupcake`de mi `dom`
para volver a pintarlos en base a un filtro.

Estoy haciendo;

```
let cupcakes= document.getElementsByClassName("cupcake");
alert(cupcakes.length);
for(element of cupcakes){
console.log(element);
container.removeChild(element);
console.log(element);
console.log("-------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

La longitud de elementos que recupero es exactamente la que necesito y los elementos tambien, pero no entiendo el que solo me elimine los impares, la salida del código anterior es la siguiente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Únicamente muestra los elementos impares ¿Por qué? Necesito eliminarlos todos, cada uno de los que recorre el bucle, si suprimo la linea de `removeChild` imprime todos los objetos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que la función [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) devuelve una lista "viva" de los elementos del HTML, a lo que me refiero es que si eliminas un elemento del HTML también lo eliminas de la lista y esto interfiere con la iteración porque los índices cambian.  Una manera de solucionarlo es creando una copia de la lista antes de iterar.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');

document.getElementById('boton').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let cupcakes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("cupcake"), 0);
  
  for(element of cupcakes){
    console.log(element);
    element.remove();
  }  
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="1" class="cupcake">1</div>
  <div id="2" class="cupcake">2</div>
  <div id="3" class="cupcake">3</div>
  <div id="4" class="cupcake">4</div>
  <div id="5" class="cupcake">5</div>
  <div id="6" class="cupcake">6</div>
  <div id="7" class="cupcake">7</div>
  <div id="8" class="cupcake">8</div>
  <div id="9" class="cupcake">9</div>
  <div id="10" class="cupcake">10</div>
</div>

<button id="boton">Probar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias! No desconocia ese comportamiento "vivo", funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: muy útil tu respuesta estaba realizando lo mismo y me di cuenta de lo que comentas, acerca de la lista viva, aun así no daba con la forma de implementarlo, solo una pequeña consulta en caso que querer borrar mas divs con otra clase de que forma se podria implementar? intente con let cupcakes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("cupcake otraClase"), 0); y con Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("cupcake", "otraClase"), 0); y no me funciono obte por repetir dos veces el mismo codigo con diferente clase pero creo que no es lo adecuado.

Answer (score 4):

Si quieres eliminar todos los elementos `div` con una clase en específico te recomiendo utilizar `JQuery`, te dejo un ejemplo donde existe un `div` con una clase distinta a `cupcake`:

```js
$( "div" ).remove( ".cupcake" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="cupcake">Prueba 1</div>
<div id="2" class="cupcake">Prueba 2</div>
<div id="3" class="cupcake">Prueba 3</div>
<div id="4" class="cupcake">Prueba 4</div>
<div id="5" class="cupcakePrueba">Prueba 5</div>
<div id="6" class="cupcake">Prueba 6</div>
```

Utilizo la función `remove` para eliminarlos del `dom`. Te dejo la documentación por si la necesitas: https://api.jquery.com/remove/. Saludos.

Comment: No se me permite el uso de `JQuery`pero gracias, nunca está de más :)

Comment: De acuerdo compañero, creo que hizo falta especificar eso en la pregunta, lo utilicé en la respuesta debido a que te puede facilitar los apuntadores al dom de manera muy rápida y sencilla, suerte y saludos.